# 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

How can I solve this problem?

```
user@user-admin:~$ autoreconf -ifv
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

Answer (score 1):

> From your comments on A.B.'s now-deleted answer, you want to build [this software](https://github.com/redpony/cdec).  This answer addresses this fact.  Next time, tell us what software you're building, what steps you've tried so far, and whether you've read any documentation relating to building the given software, so you get help faster with issues such as these.

First, you need all the build dependencies, and the fastest way to install them all is this command, which installs not only the compiler but the additional boost libraries and Flex that you'll need.  `sudo apt-get install build-essential libboost-all-dev cmake flex`

Secondly, create a directory and go into it (you said `~/prefix/sw` in your comments).

Thirdly, `git clone https://github.com/redpony/cdec.git`.

Fourthly, **you probably did not read the README page on the GitHub repository which explains what commands to run to make the software build**.  It lists these as the build steps, after `cd`-ing into the newly created `cdec` folder:

```
cmake .
make -j4
make test
./tests/run-system-tests.pl
```

Why you would run some other commands other than the ones listed in the repository documentation, I do not know.  You need to read up on how to build software, because it varies from software-to-software.  It doesn't look like you need `autoreconf` here.

Comment: @A.B. Don't be.  It helped us discover the user was failing to understand how to compile that specific software, and led to this answer here :)